# Firestore every login user with his retults

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do the best practice for my app with firestore. I need a multiple users login with his own results.
For example, now I have only one results for all users. I have some collections: students, documents, evaluation, configuration, ...
This collections returns his own documents data with code like (for example):

```
db.collection('configuration')
    .get()
    .then(function (doc) {
        doc.forEach(function(docData) {
        console.log(Data, " => ", docData.data());
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
    });
```

With this code i can return the configuration's documents data, but every user have the same results.

How can I do for return every data differents for each user logged?
For example:

- User 1 => return configuration for user 1
- User 2 => return configuration for user 2

etc...

**More specific question:**

What I need to do? Every user have their collection and in this user's collection I need to do all my subcollections with configuration, documents, students, ...

```
Collection USER1
--- Subcollection CONFIGURATION
--- Subcollection STUDENTS
--- Subcollection DOCUMENTS ...

Collection USER2
--- Subcollection CONFIGURATION
--- Subcollection STUDENTS
--- Subcollection DOCUMENTS ...
```

Or I need to do configuration, docuemtns, students, ... collections and in this documents manage the user.id?

```
Collection CONFIGURATION .doc(uid)
Collection STUDENTS .where('id', '===', user.id)
```

Comment: How do figure out which documents belong to which user?  Without knowing that, there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: With their user.id. Every user login have their user.id. I need to know how to organize my database correctly for do queries independent for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is simply use the user's ID as the ID of the document.  Then all you have to do is `get()` the document belonging to that user.  If you have the user's ID in a variable called `uid`, the query looks like this:

```
db.collection('configuration').doc(uid).get()
.then(function (snapshot) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log(Data, " => ", snapshot.data());
    }
    else {
        // decide what you want to do if the document doesn't exist
    }
})
.catch(function (error) {
    // handle the error
});
```

I suggest reading the documentation for [reading a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document).

Comment: Thanks for the doc, I read it already. But with this solution I have a problem: if i have a collection called "activities" with multiple activities for every user (user 1 -> act1, act2, act3, act4... user 2 -> act1, act2, act3, ...) I cant pass doc if with uid, so, every user login have multiple activities assigned... (sorry for my english)

Comment: OK, that sounds like a different problem to solve.  Please post the details of that separately.

Comment: I need to assign uid to a field on every activity and then do `.where('uid','==',user.id)`? Or it is better make a subcollection for every user logged?

Comment: That's entirely up to you.  Pick whatever meets your needs.

Comment: Yes, I understand it, but for the best practice what it's better? Read every subcollection for each user logged? or read the collection with a .where method?

Comment: Neither is necessarily better.  It sounds like they both work for you, so pick the one you like best.  What you're asking right now is a matter of opinion.